# Keep Browser Connection alive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, browser, signalr

my ASP.NET MVC Web-Application hostet in IIS shows an empty HTML page to the connected clients (Chrome, Firefox, Edge - all in latest version). If an event occurs, the Web Application shows some little informations, generated with SignalR. After eleven minutes, the screen goes back to the idle screen. Works only in Chrome and Firefox, Edge has already closed the connection after ten minutes. Observed with "perfmon" - "Currently Connected Clients". I have tried this over night, Firefox and Chrome are still alive and they are showing the informatio after an event accours.

But how long can the idle time be in Chrome and Firefox, can I disable this Timeout for all or in all Browsers or in the Web Application?

I have tried to send the DateTime as String through SignalR for every minute, but this works only when the Console is open...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following ways to solve the problem:

1.Stop recycling of application pool.

Go to your IIS Manager -> Select "**Application Pool**" the instance you want to manage ->Select "Advanced settings" action -> Under "Recycling" and set "Regular Time Interval" to 0.

2.Keep the ASP.NET application run always by application pool.

Go to your IIS Manager -> Select "**Application Pool**" the instance you want to manage ->Select "Advanced settings" action -> Under "(General)" and set "Start Mode" to "AlwaysRunning".

3.Set applicaton load automatically after its deployment.

Go to your IIS Manager -> Select "**the application**" you want to manage ->Select "Advanced settings" action -> Under "(General)" and set "Preload Enabled" to "true".